# How Can I Improve This Algorithm (LCS)

Tags: scheme

```
  (define (lcs lst1 lst2)
   (define (except-last-pair list)
   (if (pair? (cdr list))
   (cons (car list) (except-last-pair (cdr list)))
   '()))
  (define (car-last-pair list)
   (if (pair? (cdr list))
   (car-last-pair (cdr list))
   (car list)))
  (if (or (null? lst1) (null? lst2)) null
   (if (= (car-last-pair lst1) (car-last-pair lst2))
      (append (lcs (except-last-pair lst1) (except-last-pair lst2)) (cons (car-last-pair lst1) '()))
      (**if (> (length (lcs lst1 (except-last-pair lst2))) (length (lcs lst2 (except-last-pair lst1)))) 
          (lcs lst1 (except-last-pair lst2))
          (lcs lst2 (except-last-pair lst1))))))**
```

I dont want it to run over and over..

Regards,
Superguay

Comment: Could you perhaps describe what it does and why you find it to be bad currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that this is supposed to take the longest common subsequence of two lists.  As you noted, it's pretty slow.  You will need to take a more complicated approach than just brute-forcing it like this if you want it to work more quickly; the canonical solution is the dynamic programming algorithm described in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem).

One way you could vastly speed up your solution without totally switching to a different algorithm is through [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) of the results, since as it stands you'll be computing the same intermediate results over and over as you recurse and drop elements from the ends of the lists.

EDIT: Well, an easy way to make it a bit faster without much work would be to use a `let` clause to avoid extra work at the bottom, i.e.

```
(if (or (null? lst1) (null? lst2)) null
  (let ((front1 (except-last-pair lst1)) (front2 (except-last-pair lst2)))
    (if (= (car-last-pair lst1) (car-last-pair lst2))       
      (append (lcs front1 front2) (cons (car-last-pair lst1) '()))
      (let ((sub-lcs1 (lcs lst1 front2)) (sub-lcs2 (lcs lst2 front1)))
        (if (> (length sub-lcs1) (length sub-lcs2)) 
          sub-lcs1
          sub-lcs2))))
```

Hope it's correct - I don't have an interpreter handy - but you get the picture.

Comment: Is there any way that I can speed it up without using either memoization or dynamic programming..?.. it is just i am not familiar with these concepts...:S